# How to address an object through a string?

Tags: actionscript-3

Background:

In a shared Object in AS3, I saved the names (as Strings) of certain MovieClips that appear on stage time in my game.

Issue:

I'm trying to reverse this and the only way I found so far is a method like this:

```
function objectNameFromString(objectNameAsString): MovieClip {
    switch (objectNameAsString): {
    case "myobject":
        return myobject;
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have to make like 20 case statements to get this done which seems unneccesary =( is there anyway you can just reference a MovieClip from a String?

Comment: Use another object to act as a dictionary/lookup-container. `myObjects = {myobject: myobject}; myObjects["myobject"]`

Comment: I think such collection is the best when it comes to a predefined set of objects you can create in such a place. I use this approach to spawn different types of monsters, choosing them at runtime. Example: `var m:Monster=new MonsterCollection[monsterName]();`

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is this:
[getChildByName()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_es/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great way to code, because it bypasses type safety, but properties of any object, including your timeline, are stored as an array anyway, so if both your property and your function are in the same scope (i.e. both variables are on the main timeline, regardless of where your MovieClip is in the display heirarchy), you should just be able to use `this["myObject"];`:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var myObject:MovieClip = addChild(new MovieClip()) as MovieClip;

trace(this["myObject"]);

// Output: [object MovieClip]
```

But building a formal collection, as others have suggested, is probably a better approach, or using `getChildByName()` if all your objects share a common parent (e.g. if they are all placed directly onto the stage).